# Eliminate duplicate value generated from database into combobox

Tags: symfony, combobox, doctrine, twig

I want to eliminate duplicate product name  from the comobox, the value are generated from database (Product entity)

Is there a configuration in the buildform that eliminate duplicate value ? Or there is some code sould be written ?

---

### Update

I want to eliminate duplicate value for the user ,its confusing to have two same value ,my logic is correct (in my case) I can have two products with same name. What I have to do: The user chooses the name of a product and according to it I update it's color

---

my Controller :

```
public function addPoductAction(Request $request) { 
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ProductType');
$form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $productcombo=$form[name]->getData();
        $productcomboName = $ productcombo ->getName();
        $color=$form[‘color’]->getData();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $repository = $this
     ->getDoctrine()
     ->getManager()
     ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
 $products = $repository->findBy(
     array('name' => $productcomboName) 
 );
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product ->setColor($color);
    $em->flush();
}
return $this->redirectToRoute(‘Product_page’);
}
return $this->render('AppBundle:Product:updateProducts.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
}
```

Product entity :

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

ProductType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name',EntityType::class,array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Product', 'choice_label'=>'name'     ))

}
```

Twig :

```
<label Product name < </label>
<div>
    {{ form_widget(form.name)}}
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You'd need to make your query in doctrine `distinct` or issue a `group by`

Comment: If the query is `distinct` or uses `group by` how do you know the correct products have been fetched? If they should be different, why not enforce that in your schema?  
Having the `name` as a non-unique/nullable field that is used selecting data for a dropdown seems like inviting problems

Comment: This is logic issue. You should not select distinct names but if you have products with same name in different e.g. categories you should also display its category.  Selecting distinct product names will cause other errors.

Comment: The logic could be perfectly valid. Consider this query `SELECT p.id, p.title FROM product p INNER JOIN product_per_category ppc ON p.id = ppc.product_id`, this query makes sure your product is attached to one or more categories. Issuing a `group by p.id` here would be a valid aproach to eliminate double product because they are attached to multiple categories